# React.js - Unable to set state even though console shows correct items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code below, I am having trouble populating the labels in the code. Please inspect the code below for more information regarding this problem.

Browser logs:

```
Item 1680552000000
Item 1680638400000
...
```

`Performance` Component:

```js
function Performance() {
  const [labelsLength, setLabelsLength] = useState(0);
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const navData = await getNaData();
        console.log("NA Data from labels:", naData); // Log the naData to the console
        setNavData(navData);
        // console.log("NaData:", NaData);
        // setLabels(naData.map((_, index) => `Label ${index + 1}`));
        // setLabels(naData.map((item, index) => `Label ${index + 1}`));
        setLabels(
          navData.map((item, index) => {
            console.log("Item:", item.date); // Print the item to the console
            return `Label ${item.date}`;
          })
        );

        setLabelsLength(naData.length);
        console.log("Labels:", labels);
        console.log("After labels", naData);
        console.log("After labels length", naData.length);
        console.log("Labels length:", labelsLength);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
    console.log("data", data);
  }, [xAxisInterval]);
}
```

I am unsure of what's happening here in the code shown. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `console.log("Labels:", labels);` isn't going to show the value you just passed to `setLabels()` as, `setLabels()` will only update the `labels` state upon the next render.

Comment: Store `navData.map(...)` is a separate variable if you need to use it again within the same render, then call `setLabels()` using that variable.

Comment: Could you show us the return value of Performance? And what does it print if `useEffect(()=>{console.log(labels)},[labels])`?

Comment: 1. setLabels should take a callback in which you return navData.map(). calling it this way causes instability and not getting labels.

2. what is data in : console.log("data", data); ???? 

3. You need to clarify the problem and provide us with detailed output and code in order for us to be able to help you.